# jQuery hoverIntent submenu fades on move from submenu to main menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, settimeout

I try to create a submenu that:

- delays 1 second before it hides again for userfriendlyness (unintended loss of focus)
- fades out, so it's clear it going
- on re-entry stops the fading and fades back in

I introduced the use of hoverIntent.

It is working now with the following code (version of jQuery should be the latest, otherwise fadeIn does not work):

$(document).ready(function(){

```
function showMenu() {
    $("#speciesSubmenu").stop(true,false).fadeIn(500).show();
}

function hideMenu() {
    $("#speciesSubmenu").fadeOut(1000,0);
}

$("#menuItemSoorten").hoverIntent({
    over: showMenu,
    timeout: 800,
    out: hideMenu
});
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/johannesklapwijk/p8PDW/15/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/p8PDW/6

The stop in the handler in method is making the problem

```
$("#speciesSubmenu").stop().css("opacity", "1").show();
```

This is the change.
and for the stop() read this article http://api.jquery.com/stop/ it will help you a lot

Comment: I dont see any difference. It still behaves like the original

Comment: There is one problem left in this solution: when you hover from the submenu to the main menu it still fades away.

Comment: @JohannesKlapwijk i rewrite the whole function, if should work now : http://jsfiddle.net/p8PDW/15/

Comment: Changing the hover event to the top menu only indeed worked! Sometimes solutions are much easier then you figure.

Answer (score 0):

The set time Out is going to run and fadeOut as soon as the mouseout event fires.  Firstly you should switch to using the .on() method with the mouseenter / mouseleave events, and to really create the behavior you're after you'll want to use the hoverintent plugin available here

https://github.com/briancherne/jquery-hoverIntent

Comment: note the change to the .on method is just a best (better?) practice thing, and not essential